# Python 3: Printing multiple variables on different lines

Tags: python-3.x

apologies in advance for any errors I have made, as this is my first post and I am very new to programming

---

My goal is to assign a name with whitespace to a variable, then print that name multiple times each on a new line, while stripping the whitespace, so that the end result looks like this

```
Adam
    Adam
    Adam
    Adam
```

**What I have tried-**

```
name = " Adam "
print(name\n\tname.lstrip()\n\tname.rstrip()\n\tname.strip())
```

But this gives me is this error message (all further attempts also give me the same Syntax error)

```
File "< stdin >", line 1
print(name\n\tname.lstrip()\n\tname.rstrip()\n\tname.strip())                                                          
                                                      ^
SyntaxError: unexpected character after line continuation character
```

**The following attempt have been shortened to make it easier to read and type all of them**

I have tried changing the variable name to see if that was the problem

```
title = " Adam "
print(\n\ttitle.strip())
```

I have tried discarding the .strip() function

```
name = " Adam "
print(\n\tname)
```

I have tried adding a space

```
name = " Adam "
print(\n\t name.strip())
```

I have tried putting the \n in quotes

```
name = " Adam "
print("\n\t" name.strip())
```

I have tried putting all of it in quotes, which doesn't give me an error but also doesn't give the desired effects

```
name = " Adam "
print("\n\tname.strip()")
```

> > > name.strip()

If anyone is wondering why I would want to do this is because I am learning how to use python through "Python Crash Course" and was given this task-

2-7. Stripping Names: Store a person’s name, and include some whitespace
characters at the beginning and end of the name. Make sure you use each
character combination, "\t" and "\n", at least once.
Print the name once, so the whitespace around the name is displayed.
Then print the name using each of the three stripping functions, lstrip(),
rstrip(), and strip()

The only thing that seems to work is putting a separate print function on each line, but that defeat the purpose of using \n and \t.

or I may have misunderstood the task, in which case I feel like a silly sausage

Comment: `print("\n\t", name.strip())` and such should do the trick.

Comment: Thank you so much, worked like a charm. who knew a , had so much power?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the arguments to `print` have to be strings

```
title = " Adam "
print(\n\ttitle.strip())
```

In this example, title.strip() is a string, but putting \n\t in front of it will give you a syntax error because \ tells the interpreter that the line of code will be continued on the next line. What you need to do is make `\n\t` a string and concatinate it will the `title.strip()` string you already have.

```
title = " Adam"
print('\n\t' + title.strip())
```

This takes the string `'\n\t'` and concatenates it with the string `"Adam"` from `title.strip()` giving you the string `'\n\tAdam'` which will print your string on the next line. Alternatively, print excepts multiple arguments as input, so another acceptable way to accomplish what you want it is the following.

```
print('\n\t', title.strip())
```

All the arguments of `print` will then between printed with a single space in-between each.

```
name = " Adam "
print(name\n\tname.lstrip()\n\tname.rstrip()\n\tname.strip())
```

an easy solution is to write

```
print(name, '\n\t', name.lstrip(), '\n\t', name.rstrip(), '\n\t', name.strip())
```

or

```
print(name + '\n\t' + name.lstrip() + '\n\t' + name.rstrip() + '\n\t' + name.strip())
```

Comment: Same answer that Gassa posted, but much more in depth. Thank you.